# Using Umano SlidingUpPanel with limited drag area and drag button

Tags: android

I'm currently using the umano slidinguppanel for one of my test project but I do have one problem wherein I wanted to make the panel to only expand when I press (not click) and drag a certain image or when I click the button itself it will expand. The later is a bit easy to implement but as for the press I'm having a hard time to implement it.

for a better visual here is my XML for the panel:

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
            xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            sothree:panelHeight="120dp"
            sothree:shadowHeight="0dp"
            sothree:overlay="true"
            sothree:fadeColor="@android:color/transparent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:src="@drawable/test_img"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ic_menu"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:onClick="showDrawer" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#00ffffff">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="#00ffffff"
                    android:id="@+id/transparent_panel">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:id="@+id/ic_menu2"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:onClick="showDrawer"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:src="#00ffffff" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/img_expand"
                            android:src="@drawable/img_expand" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#66ffffff"
                    android:id="@+id/pager_container">

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
                            android:id="@+id/pager_title"
                            android:background="@color/yellow"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="top"/>

                    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Here I have a panel with image that I wanted to be the handle when expanding the drawer and on my code I tried to implement this:

```
ImageView img_expand = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_expand);

        slideLayout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
        slideLayout.setSlidingEnabled(false);

        img_expand.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                Log.e("Test", String.valueOf(event));
                Log.e("Test2", String.valueOf(event.ACTION_DOWN));
                Log.e("Test3", String.valueOf(event.getAction()));
                Log.e("Test4", String.valueOf(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN));
                Log.e("Test5", String.valueOf(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE));

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    slideLayout.setSlidingEnabled(true);
                    return true;
                }else{
                    slideLayout.setSlidingEnabled(false);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Sadly it didn't work as I expected. hope someone can guide me on this. :D

Comment: State the library version that you use right now

Comment: I use the latest version since I use gradle for my build: compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:+'